# jenkins - building xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin, jenkins, xamarin.ios, msbuild

I'm trying to build a soln with a IOS project on a jenkins machine.

The command looks like:

```
msbuild.exe /m /t:Rebuild /clp:Summary /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:ServerAddress=x.x.x.x /p:ServerUser=xxxxx  /p:ServerPassword=xxxx mysoln.sln
```

This works fine on my machine, when I login to the jenkins machine it works fine. But, when jenkins executes the build I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Windows.After.targets(90,5): error : The current connection has never been connected. It needs to be connected first in order to use it as an active connection
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

**Update**

I figured it out, there was a % in the password that I needed to escape!

Comment: Post the update part as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, there was a % in the password that I needed to escape!

Comment: Accept your own answer! :)